# How to replace values in a mat using another mat image

Tags: c++, numpy, opencv

I have a 480x480 Mat A and 478x478 Mat B. 
I want to fill Mat A (excluding the borders of A) using Mat B in C++.
In python I am using the following notation from numpy

```
A[1:-1,1:-1] = B[:,:,0]
```

To achieve the same in c++, I have tried using the following code using channels and range but it did not work.

```
std::vector<Mat> B_channel(3);
split(B, B_channel);
A(cv::Range(1,479), cv::Range(1, 479)) = B_channel[0];
```

How to achieve the same in C++.

Comment: what is the meaning of "did not work" ?

Comment: Values from B_channel are not copied to A. 
When I try to output A  I see all zeros which is what I have initialized A with i.e cv::Mat A = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(480, 480), CV_8UC1)

Comment: `B_channel[0].copyTo(A(Rect(1,1,A.cols-2, A.rows-2)));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do the same effect of your python code in C++ you can do something like the following example:

```
  cv::Mat A(100, 100, CV_8U, cv::Scalar::all(0));
  cv::Mat B(98, 98, CV_8U, cv::Scalar::all(1));
  std::cout << "sumAll A: " << cv::sum(A) << std::endl;

  B.copyTo(A.colRange(1, A.cols - 1).rowRange(1, A.rows - 1)); // This is the copy part
  std::cout << "sumAll A: " << cv::sum(A) << std::endl;
```

I print the sum of all to verify it has copied it. The firs case gave 0, and the second case gave 9604. Which is correct in both cases. An important thing to remember: If the size mismatch copyTo will reinitialize the matrix and may give unexpected results.

To breakdown the code a little bit more, this:

```
A.colRange(1, A.cols - 1).rowRange(1, A.rows - 1)
```

is equivalent to:

```
 A[1:-1,1:-1]
```

in python, and `copyTo` will copy the values (and not the header) from one cv::Mat to another one. If you use the copy operator (=) it will only copy the headers, and in this case is just writing it over a temporary header that you created with `A(cv::Range(1,479), cv::Range(1, 479))` which is more to access the data inside A. After the instruction this header gets destroyed and your data is exactly the same.

To get the header part that you want to copy to, you can do it in several ways. The one I wrote is taking range of columns and rows. Another one is the one you wrote (taking two ranges) and a third one is using a `cv::Rect`. So at the end all this is equivalent:

```
B.copyTo(A.colRange(1, A.cols - 1).rowRange(1, A.rows - 1));
B.copyTo(A(cv::Range(1, A.cols - 1), cv::Range(1, A.rows - 1)));
B.copyTo(A(cv::Rect(1,1,A.cols -2, A.rows -2)));
```

In the last case a cv::Rect is (x,y, width, height) therefore the -2 instead of -1 of the other cases.

And you can do the same to B before using copyTo to get a subset of the image B.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. What about this part B[:,:,0]

Comment: @Saikiran sadly I do not know a better way than using split as you did. However if you wish to apply the same border to all the channels you can use the same methods from before with the 3 channel matrix instead of the one with 1 channel.